# Получит сумму двух лучших значений столбца

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Есть таблица:

```
declare @Results table(ParticipId int, Mark int)

insert into @Results values (1, 10)
insert into @Results values (1, 14)
insert into @Results values (1, 13)
insert into @Results values (2, 13)
insert into @Results values (2, 13)
insert into @Results values (2, 10)

select * from @Results
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо в результирующей таблице получить **сумму двух лучших значений** по столбцу `Mark` для каждого `ParticipId`, т.е.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как составить запрос для получения такого?

Мои мысли крутятся вокруг использования обобщенных табличных выражений (CTE) и использования подзапроса к запросу где используется `ORDER BY DESC` и `TOP 2`. Но ничего практического чтобы руки могли набить не придумал.

Comment: А что значит "лучшие" значения?

Comment: Если под лучшими подразумеваются максимальные, то почему тогда для `ParticipId=1` `SumBest3Mark` равно 24, а не 27?

Comment: @Regent, да - действительно у меня там ошибка. Должно быть `27`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нумеруем записи в порядке убывания Mark в пределах ID и суммируем первую и вторую записи:

```
select ParticipId, sum(Mark)
  from (
   select ParticipId, Mark,
          row_number() over(partition by ParticipId order by Mark desc) RN
     from @Results
  ) A where RN<=2
group by ParticipId
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать оператор `CROSS APPLY` для получения суммы двух наивысших оценок `Mark` для каждого `ParticipId`

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT ParticipId
FROM @Results
GROUP BY ParticipId) g
    CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT SUM(Mark) AS SumBest3Mark
    FROM (SELECT TOP 2 Mark 
        FROM @Results
        WHERE ParticipId = g.ParticipId
        ORDER BY Mark DESC) Top2
    ) A;
```